# How to implement query parameters in Postman with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I have a driver.js that contains a driver schema. Also the driverController.js, which contains my rest methods. GET, POST, DELETE, and PUT.

What i would like to do is

GET - http://localhost:3000/drivers?available=true

and have it return all of the drivers that are available.

My driver schema simply looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DriverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    available: Boolean,
    latitude: Number,
    longitude: Number
});
mongoose.model('Driver', DriverSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Driver');
```

I looked at some [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), but I haven't been able to do anything.

Here's my GET method in which I'm attempting to add parameters

```
// GETS ALL DRIVERS FROM THE DATABASE
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Driver.find({}, function (err, driver) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the drivers.");
        var available = req.query.available;
        if (available == driver.available )
            res.status(200).send(available );
        else
            res.status(200).send("Nice! " + driver.available);
    });
});
```

This comparison doesn't ever work. It always goes to the else statement. I'm not quite sure why but the output is "Nice! undefined" Even though I have plenty of drivers in my database, and if I only put inside the else statement
    res.status(200).send("Nice! " + driver);
Then it gives me the list of drivers.

Nonetheless, I would like to be able to use query parameters in order to find drivers.

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated, as this is a project and I have never worked with restAPI, or javascript before. Thanks!

NOTE: Mongoose, express. node.js, and mongoDB are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I only put inside the else statement res.status(200).send("Nice! " + driver); Then it gives me the list of drivers.

it's a list of drivers, with `if (available == driver.available )` you're comparing a `boolean` with an array of objects,

instead of fetching all the drivers and checking if they have `availabe == true` , add the condition to the `.find()` and return the result :

```
// GETS ALL DRIVERS FROM THE DATABASE
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Driver.find({ available : req.query.available }, function (err, drivers) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the drivers.");
        res.status(200).send(drivers);
    });
});
```

EDIT :

you can do this to add filter depending on the query string :

```
// GETS ALL DRIVERS FROM THE DATABASE
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        var params = {};
        Object.keys(req.query).forEach((v, k) => params[k] = v);

        Driver.find(params, function (err, drivers) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the drivers.");
            res.status(200).send(drivers);
        });
    });
```

having `?name=Wario&available=true` will create an object like `{ name : 'wario', available : true` and pass it to the `.find()`

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response! I have a question, however, this seems to limit my GET method flexibility, as now I can't get all users. if i simply call the get method with "/drivers" But I would like to know also, if i can do this so that i can also search by name, or just use any combination of the attributes from the schema

Comment: applying the filter to your `find()` doesn't mean it becomes `LIMITED` but rather `Optimized` as you're not fetching the data you don't need from the DB, and yes, you can add as many filters as you want like `{ available : req.query.available , name : req.query.name }` ...etc.

Comment: Fair enough. When i mean limited, it just seems that it has to become very specific. For example If i were to add all of the attributes from the schema above, then it looks like I can no longer search by name only. I have to know all of the values, right?

Is there a way for me to be able to add all of the parameters and still be able to choose to search by one or two? such as:

GET - http://localhost:3000/drivers?name=Wario&available=true

Comment: I added a few if statements [if (req.query.name).. and such and that answered my question. thanks!!!